# file.listFiles() does not list recently created file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a component that should do something every time a file in the watched directory is created,updated or deleted.
For the sake of simplicity, lets say it prints the file names to Sysout.

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    MyComponentWatcher myComponentWatcher

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        myComponentWatcher.registerWatchService();
    }
}

@Component
public class MyComponentWatcher {
    @Value("${somePath}")
    private String myPath;

    private File myDir;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.myDir = new File(myPath);
    }

    @Async
    public void registerWatchService() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watchService
                = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path path = myDir.toPath();

        path.register(
                watchService,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Event kind:" + event.kind()
                                + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
            }
            key.reset();

            File[] files = myDir.listFiles();
            System.out.println(files); //!!!
        }
    }
}
```

GIVEN my dir contains 1 file
WHEN I create another file
THEN System.out.println(files); returns the old and the new file
-> **I only get the old file!**

I wrote a test case that uses `Files.write(filePath, fileContent.getBytes(), CREATE_NEW);` to create the test file and

```java
    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        File toDelete = new File(filePath.toString());
        toDelete.delete();
    }
```

to delete the test file after the test.

In total the watcher triggers 3 times with the following lists of events:

1. [ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY]
2. [ENTRY_MODIFY]
3. [ENTRY_MODIFY]
4. [ENTRY_DELETE]

Comment: have you tried this , File[] files = new File(myPath).listFiles();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine as expected and written.
to achieve your output, you need to recreate the object for `File` class.

```
// we are creating the object just after the constructor
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.myDir = new File(myPath);
}
```

but then you modified your path but not the actual instance variable:

please change your code `File[] files = new File(myPath).listFiles();`